# Case statements in PL/SQL functions

Tags: database, oracle, function, plsql

I'm running into the error trying to compile a function.

> PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL
>   statement only

Here is the Function.

```
 create or replace function get_ulq (
    i_vcust_cd IN VARCHAR2,
    i_vordr_type IN VARCHAR2,
    i_vpart_no IN VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2 
  AS
    ulq_count varchar2(50 char) := null; 
  BEGIN 
    CASE WHEN exists ( SELECT count(*)
                         FROM P1.p7ulqpm0
                        WHERE cust_cd = i_vcust_cd
                          AND src     = i_vordr_type
                          AND part_no = i_vpart_no)
        then  select ulq 
                into ulq_count
               from p1.p2partm0
              where src = i_vordr_type
                and part_no = i_vpart_no;
        ELSE ulq_count := 1;
    END CASE;
    RETURN ulq_count;
  END get_ulq;
```

Comment: And count(*) exists always :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any advice on how to alter this statement? Should I add >= 1 for the count?

Comment: (Select count(*) ... ) >= 1.  Or you can make select count into var1 and use if

Comment: The issue was around `EXISTS`, not `CASE`. If you'd [searched the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?word=exists&product=e50529-01&book=LNPLS) you might have noticed that your `if exists (cursor)` construction doesn't appear anywhere.